# Erro ao inicializar DataTable com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Olá, Tenho um DataTable que será alimentado com JavaScript Source (fonte de dados)
ao abrir a tela, quero que ele seja iniciado "vazio", sem dados.

Por algum motivo, ele já é iniciado automaticamente ao carregar o jquery.datatable.js, e preciso destruir ele e iniciar com minhas configurações.
Ai que vem o problema. Segue o Codigo:

```
var table = $('#'+id);  

        table.DataTable().destroy();

        var oTable = table.DataTable( {
                "dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>", // datatable layout without  horizobtal scroll
                "scrollY": "300",                               
                "deferRender": true,
                "responsive":true,
                "bAutoWidth": true,                 
                "order": [
                    [0, 'asc']
                    ],
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [5, 15, 20, -1],
                        [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
                        ],
                        "pageLength": 15, // set the initial value  
                data: dataSet,                  
                columns: columns
            } );                

        var tableWrapper = $('#'+id+'_wrapper'); // datatable creates the table wrapper by adding with id {your_table_jd}_wrapper
        tableWrapper.addClass('col-md-12');
        tableWrapper.find('.dataTables_length select').select2(); // initialize select2 dropdown
```

na linha `table.DataTable().destroy();` da o erro

> Exception caught: Exception caught: Exception caught: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Não sei como resolver, pois se não dou o destroy(), recebo a mensagem que não posso inicializar duas vezes meu datatable, e se tento destruir pra recriar, recebo o erro aqui citado.
Qualquer ajuda é bem vida.

Comment: Vamos precisar do HTML que gera a tabela.

Comment: meu html da tabela é simples
`<table id="myTable" class="datatable"></table>`
visto que as colunas e dados, não são feitos pelo DOM.